# how use xslt to get value from structure in table row

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have following data structure:
There is some table[n]. In each table cell there is some structure which contains e.g. fields for users, like: name, surename, address, etc.
There is my code, which I want to get data from first cell from table:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="//uf:field[@name='table']//uf:fv[1]//uf:address/uf:MIEJSCOWOSC" />
```

The problem is, data are not showing up.
There is some problem inside my select. Anybody knows what is wrong?

There is part of my xml fiel with relevant data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.xxx.pl" xmlns:uf="http://www.xxx.pl">
<ApplicationData>
<complex>
<field name="table">
    <fv>
      <t.0>
        <address type="address">
          <KOD_POCZTOWY type="String">^KOD_POCZTOWY^</KOD_POCZTOWY>
          <KRAJ type="String">^KRAJ^</KRAJ>
          <MIEJSCOWOSC type="String">^MIEJSCOWOSC^</MIEJSCOWOSC>
          <NR_BUDYNKU type="String">^NR_BUDYNKU^</NR_BUDYNKU>
          <NR_LOKALU type="String">^NR_LOKALU^</NR_LOKALU>
          <TELEFON type="String">^TELEFON^</TELEFON>
          <TYP_ADRESU type="String">^TYP_ADRESU^</TYP_ADRESU>
          <TYP_ULICY type="String">^TYP_ULICY^</TYP_ULICY>
          <ULICA type="String">^ULICA^</ULICA>
          <ID type="String">^ID^</ID>
        </address>
      </t.0>
      <t.1>
        <address type="address">
          <KOD_POCZTOWY type="String">^KOD_POCZTOWY^</KOD_POCZTOWY>
          <KRAJ type="String">^KRAJ^</KRAJ>
          <MIEJSCOWOSC type="String">^MIEJSCOWOSC^</MIEJSCOWOSC>
          <NR_BUDYNKU type="String">^NR_BUDYNKU^</NR_BUDYNKU>
          <NR_LOKALU type="String">^NR_LOKALU^</NR_LOKALU>
          <TELEFON type="String">^TELEFON^</TELEFON>
          <TYP_ADRESU type="String">^TYP_ADRESU^</TYP_ADRESU>
          <TYP_ULICY type="String">^TYP_ULICY^</TYP_ULICY>
          <ULICA type="String">^ULICA^</ULICA>
          <ID type="String">^ID^</ID>
        </address>
      </t.1>
    </fv>
  </field>
```

I add my xslt file:

```
<encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:uf="http://www.xxx.pl" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:ibex="http://www.xmlpdf.com/2003/ibex/Format" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl uf"
>
  <xsl:include href="../subs/xxx.xslt"/>
  <xsl:include href="../subs/xxxx.xslt"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:variable name="line-height" select="18"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <xsl:call-template name="layout-master-set">
        <xsl:with-param name="margin_TB" select="'0cm'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="margin_LR" select="'0cm'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="header_extent" select="'5.25cm'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="footer_extent" select="'5.25cm'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default">
        <fo:flow flow-name="body" line-height="12.0pt" font-family="Trebuchet MS" font-size="10.0pt">
             <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                  <fo:inline font-weight="normal">text</fo:inline>
                  <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
              <fo:inline font-weight="normal">City</fo:inline> 
            </fo:block>
             <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="8pt">
            </fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" />
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" margin-left="11.11cm" />
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" margin-left="11.11cm" />
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" margin-left="11.11cm">  
                      <xsl:value-of select="//uf:field[@name='table']//uf:fv[1]//uf:address//uf:MIEJSCOWOSC" />
</fo:block>
```

Comment: We need the relevant source xml as well please.

Comment: Is the namespace for prefix "uf" in the XSLT stylesheet defined exactly the same as in the XML?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Perhaps showing a small (but complete) sample of your XSLT, that demonstrates the problem fully would help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is very strange situation, but the code which yesterday were not working, today works ;/ 
If you have the same problem like me, restart machine ;]